# FOSUserBundle: How to know which users are online

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOS Rest Bundle and I'd like to show which users are online in the website. I don't know (I couldn't find any info about it) if there's a way to query the database and get if a user is currently online or not.

Is there a way to know this or any other bundle that could provide this info?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not a matter of PHP or symfony or fosuerbundle: you should implement a client side solution like - but it's neither very effective nor performing - sending an ajax request every minute with user ID: if no calls have reached your server, you can be pretty sure that user is not connected anymore. Of course this is not a solution at all for me, you could use web socket as well and so on, I just want to point your point of you to a different angle ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "lastActivity" (datetime) attribute in your User class and use an event for update the date of this field everytime the user do an action on the site.

After that, just get all online user in last x minutes with a simple doctrine query on this field.